# Does DisplayPort 1.4 support 4K@144Hz HDR?

Tags: resolution, bandwidth, displayport, mini-displayport

I bought an Asus PG32UQ monitor recently and connect it using a mini DP (eDP 1.4) with my [HP ZBook Fury 15.6 Inch G8](https://h20195.www2.hp.com/v2/GetDocument.aspx?docname=c07606964). And to my surprise, I can run at 4K on 144Hz with HDR enabled.

[image]

This is a bit confusing to me, because according to Wikipedia, only 98 Hz should be possible (or 120 without HDR) ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#Refresh_frequency_limits_for_HDR_video)). So where is the trick? Is it because of chroma subsampling?

Comment: It seems to me that this just indicates that your rig supports Ultra High Bit Rate.

Answer (score 0):

Basic calculation:

30 bits => 4 bytes (32 bits) per color channel.
3 color channels (RGB! ?)
3840 by 2140 pixels, of 3x4 bytes each
... at 144Hz

=> 3840 * 2140 * 3 * 4 * 144 => 14200012800 bytes per second
RAW 13542.1875 MiB/s to transfer through your cable.

*This might differ from the actual transfer speed in your cable, due to various "tricks" being in use (e.g. compression!).*

Practical requirement: It should be possible to check if computer display hardware, cable and monitor all are capable of the above.